# How to set the html of the <p> element in a loop

Tags: jquery

'I have tried this in a  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wbqsmk8/) and I can't get the `<p>` element to update with the html.

Any reason why?

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
setInterval(function() {
    if (ts>1) {
    alert("done"); // If I include this line I get an alert
    $('p').html('<a href=http://www.getit.com?ts='+ts.val+'"Go</a>');
    ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I found 3 errors you should fix. ts.val is undefined you don't need val just ts will do.

Comment: in your <a> the ' " is not right fix it.

Comment: and use change html() to append().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor isn't appearing because the resulting markup for it is incomplete, lacking the opening `"` for the `href` and a `>` before `Go`:

```
<a href=http://www.getit.com?ts=..."Go</a>

<!-- vs. -->
<a href="http://www.getit.com?ts=...">Go</a>
```

Also, the number stored in `ts` doesn't have a `.val` property. Using it will always result in `undefined` being concatenated rather than the timestamp.

```
console.log(ts);     // 141...
console.log(ts.val); // undefined
```

```
<a href="http://www.getit.com?ts=undefined">Go</a>
```

---

Resolving both of these should allow it to display with the `ts` updated by the interval.

```
$('p').html('<a href="http://www.getit.com?ts='+ts+'">Go</a>');
//                   ^                          ^^   ^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9x4skpcL/

Answer (score 1):

Enclose URL by double quotes. (eg, `href="your_url"`)

```js
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    setInterval(function() {
       if (ts > 1) {
           $('p').html('<a href="http://www.getit.com?ts='+ ts +'">Go</a>');
           ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
       }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Also `ts.val` is `undefined`. It can be only `ts` instead of `ts.val`

Comment: if you use html() it won't loop, it will keep overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8wbqsmk8/2/

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
setInterval(function() {
    if (ts>1) {
    $('p').append('<a href="http://www.getit.com?ts='+ts+'">Go</a>');
    ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to apply a class to the p tag. Doing this you can change your code with

```
 $('.yourclassname').html...
```

However, you have a syntax error in your code.

```
 $('p) instead of $('p')
```